# Add some views before displaying GLkit View - Navigate to GLkit View from a UIview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, opengl-es, glkit

I am making a basic application in opengles, and I started with "[raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5223/beginning-opengl-es-2-0-with-glkit-part-1)" Glkit tutorial. This displays a cube in the starting screen of the app. And he mentioned the below lines in his tutorial to do this.

> To make this Storyboard run on startup, open HelloGLKit-Info.plist,
>   control-click in the blank area, and select Add Row. From the dropdown
>   select Main storyboard file base name, and enter MainStoryboard.

**My questions:**

1) I need to add a view before starting the the GLKIT view. How can I do this? From that UIview I need to change over to GLkit view? How to do this?

2) I need to access the values I used in previous UIviews, say "x=10,y=20" in GLkit view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical iOS beginner tutorial material, [have a look at this](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/) and if it doesn't suit your needs, their are tons of other tutorials out there. the task is quite laborious to explain, but it is simple so dont worry.